# How to find all expressions ending with "<tr" (stringi package)

Tags: html, regex, r, string, stringi

I have some string which actually is HTML code to create table, for example

```
z <- "<TABLE ALIGN=\"RIGHT\" BORDER CELLSPACING=\"0\" CELLPADDING=\"0\">
   <CAPTION><B>MESA HIGH VICTORIES</B></CAPTION>
   <TH>Team</TH>
   <TH>Score</TH>
   <TR ALIGN=\"CENTER\">
   <TD><B>Parkfield High Demons</B></TD>
   <TD><B>28 to 21</B></TD>
   </TR>
   <TR ALIGN=\"CENTER\">
   <TD><B>Burns High Badgers</B></TD>
   <TD><B>14 to 13</B></TD>
   </TR>
   </TABLE>"
```

I want to extract the expression

`<TABLE ALIGN=\"RIGHT\" BORDER CELLSPACING=\"0\" CELLPADDING=\"0\">
       <CAPTION><B>MESA HIGH VICTORIES</B></CAPTION>
       <TH>Team</TH>
       <TH>Score</TH>
       <TR`

So I want extract the parts of the string which starts with `<TABLE` and ends with first `"<TR"`

The best I could do is to use function from `stringi` package

`stri_extract_all_regex(z, "(?i)\\<table.*?\\>(\\s+)?(\\<caption,*? \\>)?")`

The output

`[[1]]
[1] "<TABLE ALIGN=\"RIGHT\" BORDER CELLSPACING=\"0\" CELLPADDING=\"0\">\n   "`

but still it is not what I ment. The only obligatory part of the string before first `"<TR"` is `"<TABLE"` with some settings, caption and headers are optional. And ideas how to create proper regex for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<TABLE\b[^>]+>[\s\S]+?<TR
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vF0kU2/7

Comment: in r this would be, `pattern <- "<TABLE\\b[^>]+>[\\s\\S]+?<TR"; cat(regmatches(z, gregexpr(pattern, z, perl = TRUE))[[1]])`

Answer (score 3):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
z <- "<TABLE ALIGN=\"RIGHT\" BORDER CELLSPACING=\"0\" CELLPADDING=\"0\">
   <CAPTION><B>MESA HIGH VICTORIES</B></CAPTION>
   <TH>Team</TH>
   <TH>Score</TH>
   <TR ALIGN=\"CENTER\">
   <TD><B>Parkfield High Demons</B></TD>
   <TD><B>28 to 21</B></TD>
   </TR>
   <TR ALIGN=\"CENTER\">
   <TD><B>Burns High Badgers</B></TD>
   <TD><B>14 to 13</B></TD>
   </TR>
   </TABLE>"

library(rex)
re_matches(z,
  rex(
    capture(name='table',
      "<TABLE", zero_or_more(any, type = 'lazy'), "<TR"
    )
  ), options='single-line')
```

However I would not suggest parsing HTML with regular expressions at all.  You may want to look into using the [XML package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) or [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) instead.